# cannot assign to global variable in Python submodule

Tags: python, global-variables, python-module

I'm confused after 25 years of Python programming.
Why this contraption (squeezed to the minimum) prints "None"? I would expect "thing.implementation1.Juggernaut object at 0xblahblahblah". What is going on here?

**main.py**

```py
import thing
thing.run()
```

**thing/__init__.py**

```py
from .implementation1 import init
from .implementation1.main import *
```

**thing/implementation1/__init__.py**

```py
foo = None
class Juggernaut:
    pass
def init():
    global foo
    foo = Juggernaut()
```

**thing/implementation1/main.py**

```py
from . import init, foo
def run():
    init()
    print(repr(foo))
```

Comment: `from x import y` is like an assignment. If you set variable `y` to `x.y` and then something reassigns `x.y`, would you expect `y` also to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a practical solution, but still do not understand why it works.
Moving of the "init" function from `thing/implementation1/__init__.py` to `thing/implementation1/main.py` fixes the issue.

**thing/__init__.py**

```py
from .implementation1.main import *
```

**thing/implementation1/__init__.py**

```py
foo = None
class Juggernaut:
    pass
```

**thing/implementation1/main.py**

```py
from . import Juggernaut
def init():
    global foo
    foo = Juggernaut()
def run():
    init()
    print(repr(foo))
```